# Using R to match similar strings

Tags: r, pattern-matching, similarity

I have an item (A) plus another list of possible matches (B).

I am looking for a technique (preferably in R) which would return the best match in list B for the item A.

For example

Item

- Title: Baby One More Time
- Artist: Britney Spears
- Length: 4:01

List

- Title|Length|Views|Channel
- Britney Spears - ...Baby One More
  Time|3.57|253292922|BritneySpearsVEVO
- Britney Spears Hit Me Baby One More Time Official Music Video
  HQ|0.46|12345|nevernever
- Britney Spears -- Hit Me Baby One More Time (Video Cover)|2|21|9876|scoobydoo
- Britney Spears - Baby One More Time (Uncut Version)|3.43|23627|Benjo4EverStudioXDL
- Britney Spears - Oops!...I Did It Again (Official Video)|4.12|183483929|BritneySpearsVEVO

Obviously the best match would be the first one, and most of the elements in the list would help point to that answer. What would be the best way to figure this out in R?

Ideally it would return a 100% likelihood for #1 and then something significantly less than 100% for the others.

I am looking for a pointer, which I can then go away and research.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually from 4:01 to 3:57 would not give you 100%. Besides that, it would help if you could separate the fields appropriately (the first is the Title, the second the Artist, the third the Length). Take a look at Levenshtein distance, this could help you. It's the function adist() in R.